# XML Parsing Python ElementTree - Nested for loops

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and ElementTree (Python 3) to create a dataframe and save as csv from an XML file. Here is the XML format (in Estonian):

```
<asutused hetk="2020-04-14T03:53:33" ver="2">
    <asutus>
        <registrikood>10000515</registrikood>
        <nimi>Osaühing B.Braun Medical</nimi>
        <aadress />
        <tegevusload>
            <tegevusluba>
                <tegevusloa_number>L04647</tegevusloa_number>
                <alates>2019-12-10</alates>
                <kuni />
                <loaliik_kood>1</loaliik_kood>
                <loaliik_nimi>Eriarstiabi</loaliik_nimi>
                <haiglaliik_kood />
                <haiglaliik_nimi />
                <tegevuskohad>
                    <tegevuskoht>
                        <aadress>Harju maakond, Tallinn, Mustamäe linnaosa, J. Sütiste tee 17/1</aadress>
                        <teenused>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0038</kood>
                                <nimi>ambulatoorsed üldkirurgiateenused</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0236</kood>
                                <nimi>õe vastuvõtuteenus</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                        </teenused>
                    </tegevuskoht>
                    <tegevuskoht>
                        <aadress>Harju maakond, Tallinn, Mustamäe linnaosa, J. Sütiste tee 17/1</aadress>
                        <teenused>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0038</kood>
                                <nimi>ambulatoorsed üldkirurgiateenused</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0236</kood>
                                <nimi>õe vastuvõtuteenus</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                        </teenused>
                    </tegevuskoht>
                </tegevuskohad>
            </tegevusluba>
            <tegevusluba>
                <tegevusloa_number>L04651</tegevusloa_number>
                <alates>2019-12-11</alates>
                <kuni />
                <loaliik_kood>2</loaliik_kood>
                <loaliik_nimi>Õendusabi</loaliik_nimi>
                <haiglaliik_kood />
                <haiglaliik_nimi />
                <tegevuskohad>
                    <tegevuskoht>
                        <aadress>Harju maakond, Tallinn, Mustamäe linnaosa, J. Sütiste tee 17/1</aadress>
                        <teenused>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0038</kood>
                                <nimi>ambulatoorsed üldkirurgiateenused</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0236</kood>
                                <nimi>õe vastuvõtuteenus</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                        </teenused>
                    </tegevuskoht>
                    <tegevuskoht>
                        <aadress>Harju maakond, Tallinn, Mustamäe linnaosa, J. Sütiste tee 17/1</aadress>
                        <teenused>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0038</kood>
                                <nimi>ambulatoorsed üldkirurgiateenused</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                            <teenus>
                                <kood>T0236</kood>
                                <nimi>õe vastuvõtuteenus</nimi>
                            </teenus>
                        </teenused>
                    </tegevuskoht>
                </tegevuskohad>
            </tegevusluba>
        </tegevusload>
        <tootajad>
            <tootaja>
                <kood>D03091</kood>
                <eesnimi>Evo</eesnimi>
                <perenimi>Kaha</perenimi>
                <kutse_kood>11</kutse_kood>
                <kutse_nimi>Arst</kutse_nimi>
                <erialad>
                    <eriala>
                        <kood>E420</kood>
                        <nimi>üldkirurgia</nimi>
                    </eriala>
                </erialad>
            </tootaja>
            <tootaja>
                <kood>N01146</kood>
                <eesnimi>Karmen</eesnimi>
                <perenimi>Mežulis</perenimi>
                <kutse_kood>15</kutse_kood>
                <kutse_nimi>Õde</kutse_nimi>
            </tootaja>
            <tootaja>
                <kood>N01153</kood>
                <eesnimi>Nele</eesnimi>
                <perenimi>Terras</perenimi>
                <kutse_kood>15</kutse_kood>
                <kutse_nimi>Õde</kutse_nimi>
            </tootaja>
            <tootaja>
                <kood>N02767</kood>
                <eesnimi>Helena</eesnimi>
                <perenimi>Tern</perenimi>
                <kutse_kood>15</kutse_kood>
                <kutse_nimi>Õde</kutse_nimi>
            </tootaja>
            <tootaja>
                <kood>N12882</kood>
                <eesnimi>Hanna</eesnimi>
                <perenimi>Leemet</perenimi>
                <kutse_kood>15</kutse_kood>
                <kutse_nimi>Õde</kutse_nimi>
            </tootaja>
        </tootajad>
    </asutus>
</asutused>
```

Each "asutus" is a hospital and I need some of the information inside. Here is my code:

```
tree = ET.parse("od_asutused.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing
data = open('EE.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(data, delimiter=';')
head = []

count = 0
for member in root.findall('asutus'):
    hospital = []
    if count == 0:
        ident = member.find('registrikood').tag
        head.append(id)
        name = member.find('nimi').tag
        head.append(name)
        address = member.find('aadress').tag
        head.append(address)
        facility_type = member.find('./tegevusload/tegevusluba/haiglaliik_nimi').tag
        head.append(facility_type)
        site_address = member.find('./tegevusload/tegevusluba/tegevuskohad/tegevuskoht/aadress').tag
        head.append(site_address)
        for elem in member.findall('tegevusload'):
            list_specs = elem.find('./tegevusluba/tegevuskohad/tegevuskoht/teenused/teenus/nimi').tag
            head.append(list_specs)
        csvwriter.writerow(head)
        count = count + 1

    ident = member.find('registrikood').text
    hospital.append(ident)
    name = member.find('nimi').text
    hospital.append(name)
    address = member.find('aadress').text
    hospital.append(address)
    facility_type = member.find('./tegevusload/tegevusluba/haiglaliik_nimi').text
    hospital.append(facility_type)
    site_address = member.find('./tegevusload/tegevusluba/tegevuskohad/tegevuskoht/aadress').text
    hospital.append(site_address)
    for spec in elem.findall('tegevusload'):
        list_specs = spec.find('./tegevusluba/tegevuskohad/tegevuskoht/teenused/teenus/nimi').text
        hospital.append(list_specs)
    csvwriter.writerow(hospital)
data.close()

#Upload csv for geocoding
df = pd.read_csv(r'EE.csv', na_filter= False, delimiter=';')

#Rename columns
df.rename(columns = {'<built-in function id>':'id', 
                     'nimi':'name',
                     'aadress':'address',
                     'haiglaliik_nimi':'facility_type',
                     'haiglaliik_kood':'facility_type_c',
                     'aadress.1':'site_address',
                     'nimi.1':'list_specs'},
          inplace = True) 

#Add columns
df['country'] = 'Estonia' 
df['cc'] = 'EE'

df.head(10)
```

And the result of the df.head(10):

[Result of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1QvY.png)

The "list_specs" is blank no matter what I do. How can I populate this field with a list of each 'nimi' for each site address? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in your code the following points to change:

1. At least on my computer, calling *csv.writer* causes that newline chars
   are **doubled**. The remedy I found is to open the output file with
   additional parameters:

   ```
   data = open('EE.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8')
   ```
2. There is no sense to write *head* with Estonian column names and then
   rename the columns. Note also that in `head.append(id)` you use an undeclared
   variable (*id*).
   But this is not so important, as I changed this whole section with writing
   **target** column names (see below).
3. As you write the CSV file to be read by *read_csv*, it should contain a
   **fixed** number of columns. So it is a bad practice to use a loop to write
   one element.
4. Your instruction `list_specs = elem.findall(...)` was wrong, because
   *elem* is not set in the current loop. Instead you should use *member* (but
   I solved this detail other way).
5. There is no sense to create a variable only in order to use it once.
   More concise and readable code is e.g. `hospital.append(member.findtext('nimi'))`.
6. To avoid long *XPath* expressions, with repeated initial part, I decided
   to set a temporary variable "in the middle" of this path, e.g.
   `tgvLb = member.find('tegevusload/tegevusluba')` and then use a relative
   *XPath* starting from this node.
7. Your *rename* instruction contains one not needed column, namely *facility_type_c*. You read only **6** columns, not **7**.

So change the middle part of your code to:

```
data = open('EE.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8')
csvwriter = csv.writer(data, delimiter=';')
head = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'facility_type', 'site_address', 'list_specs']
csvwriter.writerow(head)
for member in root.findall('asutus'):
    hospital = []
    hospital.append(member.findtext('registrikood'))
    hospital.append(member.findtext('nimi'))
    hospital.append(member.findtext('aadress'))
    tgvLb = member.find('tegevusload/tegevusluba')
    hospital.append(tgvLb.findtext('haiglaliik_nimi'))
    tgvKoht = tgvLb.find('tegevuskohad/tegevuskoht')
    hospital.append(tgvKoht.findtext('aadress'))
    hospital.append(tgvKoht.findtext('teenused/teenus/nimi'))
    csvwriter.writerow(hospital)
data.close()
df = pd.read_csv(r'EE.csv', na_filter= False, delimiter=';')
```

and drop *df.rename* from your code.